# Camera position from FBX to Blender

Tags: import

I'm trying to import a scene originally made (by someone else) in C4D and exported in FBX.
Everything seems ok, except for the position and settings of the camera.

I've noticed that if I import the same FBX in Substance Painter, the camera is set correctly (so I suppose the problem is Blender's interpretation).

Does anyone know how may I solve the issue?

Comment: How exactly is the position wrong ? Might be just a factor of 10, or a unit translation problem (imperial / metric)

Comment: It's facing the opposite side of the scene. I tried to rotate it 180degrees, but it's not reflecting the intended position, and the zoom level seems wrong too (not sure about the latter though).

Comment: I think simply rotation the camera 180 degrees would make it upside down. Try this: Put the 3D cursor on the world origin (0,0,0), set the pivot point to 3D cursor and then scale the camera -1 on the appropriate axis.